# Are there any ways of speeding up rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For me, no matter what rake task has been executed, it's at least 20 seconds. The time is too long.

My OS: windows xp, rails: 2.3.8, ruby: 1.8.7

---

**UPDATE**

Are there any ways of speeding up rake? Someone said upgrade to ruby 1.9, but I don't know does it work well with rails 2.3.8? (I see in the rails' website, they recommend ruby 1.8.7)

Comment: A more useful question probably would have been "Are there any ways of speeding up rake?" followed by your problem. This question cannot have a definite answer.

Comment: @Jamie, Yes, thank you! That is what I want to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Installing_Ruby#Windows_is_slow